# Swift textfield deletes text when segmented control is touched.

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, uisegmentedcontrol, first-responder

I have a textfield that inputs a number, and that number is converted into different units depending on the selection of a segmented control. My problem is that if the textfield is still being edited - and then the segmented control is selected, the textfield deletes the data that was entered.

Just to clarify: I enter an amount into the textfield, and while the text field is still selected I click the segmented control, and the textfield displays zero, erasing the value that I originally inputted.

I'm not positive if this is default behavior, or just the flow of my program.

Comment: This definitely isn't default UIKit behaviour – sounds like there is something wrong with the logic in your program.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will dig into my logic then!

Comment: Thanks @samsymons, turns out it was my logic! Appreciate the quick response!